# 1998 Chevy K1500 - What is this hose for?

Tags: chevrolet, k1500

I just finished replacing my intake manifold gaskets.  While reinstalling the fuel line bracket, I found this hose toward the rear of the engine.  I checked my disassembly notes and photos and I don't have any recollection of having disconnected it from anything.

What is this hose for?

Some more info:

- It also doesn't have any more slack in the hose to pull any further forward.
- It connects to something just forward of the fuel tank (2nd photo) (forgive my ignorance, but I don't know the name of what it connects to)
- It has a hose clamp, but its about 12" from the end of the hose. (but that makes me think its supposed to connect to something)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: My first thought is that this is the purge line from the charcoal canister.  It's possible it's been disconnected for a long time.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but I'd bet this tube (and the connector behind it) are supposed to be part of the purge system and attached to a charcoal canister or purge solenoid which is not longer there. (Note: Just read @jwh20's comment, so seems they agrees with me.)

Comment: If you're talking about the wire connector behind it, thats for the distributor. The purge solenoid is on the passenger side of the intake manifold, and is connected. Photo: http://imgur.com/a/aA24kJk

Comment: @AdamKonieska - Maybe a better picture of what it's connected to underneath the vehicle? With what its attached to, is that object connected to anything?

Comment: @Paulster2 - added images to the question.  This is two shots from the side, with reference points labeled:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7V3G.jpg  I'm not knowledgeable enough to know what all the connecting parts are called.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of googling, I think its a vent hose off the transfer case.  Would love a second opinion on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i just finished a job with same trans . thats  the only hose that comes off of the top of the case is the vent tube , and also connects to another hose then runs over to frame rail and up to top of firewall. hope this helps 37yrs greasy, experience.